# Unicode regular expression tutorial

Tags: java, regex, unicode, globalization

Is there a good tutorial available for changing ASCII regular expressions to [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) regular expressions? I need to convert existing a US English application to support internationalization.

Comment: Hey, you could always ask a question here: This is my ASCII-only regex - what do I need to do to make it Unicode-ready? Another vital question, by the way: Which Java version are you using? Before Java 7, Unicode support in regexes [is, let's say, incomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions).

Comment: just use this \P{Cn}

Answer (score 3):

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) has some pretty good info. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) is probably a good start.