# Regex modifier /u in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, regex, unicode

Recently I have created a regex, for my PHP code which allows only the letters (including special characters plus spaces), but now I'm having a problem with converting it (?) into the JavaScript compatible regex, here it is: `/^[\s\p{L}]+$/u`, the problem is the `/u` modifier at the end of the regex pattern, as the JavaScript doesn't allow such flag.

How can I rewrite this, so it will work in the JavaScript as well?

Is there something to allow only Polish characters: `Ł`, `Ą,` `Ś`, `Ć`, ...

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6381892/558021) will be helpful here.

Comment: Are you sure you need the u flag? Have you tried removing it and testing the expression?

Comment: @cammil "u" is required so the "\p{L}" is recognized as checking for UTF-8 letters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `/u` modifier is for **unicode** support.
Support for it was added to **JavaScript** in ES2015.

Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode to learn more information about unicode in regex with JavaScript.

---

#### Polish characters:

```
Ą \u0104
Ć \u0106
Ę \u0118
Ł \u0141
Ń \u0143
Ó \u00D3
Ś \u015A
Ź \u0179
Ż \u017B
ą \u0105
ć \u0107
ę \u0119
ł \u0142
ń \u0144
ó \u00F3
ś \u015B
ź \u017A
ż \u017C
```

All special Polish characters:

```
[\u0104\u0106\u0118\u0141\u0143\u00D3\u015A\u0179\u017B\u0105\u0107\u0119\u0142\u0144\u00F3\u015B\u017A\u017C]
```

Comment: One might argue that the modifier isn't needed in any language/environment that properly handles Unicode instead of a mishmash of binary data and actual Unicode text in strings such as PHP.

Comment: @Joey - The PHP `preg` functions, which are based on PCRE, support Unicode when the `/u` option is appended to the regular expression.

Comment: @Scott - Polish language use latin, so go with ranges `[\u0000-\u007F]` = Basic Latin; `[\u0080-\u00FF]` = Latin-1 Supplement; `[\u0100-\u017F]` = Latin Extended-A; `[\u0180-\u024F]` = Latin Extended-B; ... which together get `[\u0000-\u024F]` to include all latin characters :)

Comment: Ωmega, I know why the flag is needed in PCRE and fundamentally it's the problem that PHP doesn't have a defined character set for strings, leading to some strings being in some legacy character set, some in UTF-8, some storing even non-text binary data. Environments such as Java or .NET have it far easier in that regard, given that text is always Unicode.

Comment: This answer is one of the first results on Google when searching for "regex u flag", so you might want to update it with a preface stating that it has been defined in ES2016 and is now supported by most recent browsers :)

Comment: @Ωmega If you only want to catch letters, you could use: `[\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02B8]` but it certainly doesn't look at neat.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript doesn't have any notion of UTF-8 strings, so it's unlikely that you need the `/u` flag. (Your strings are probably already in the usual JavaScript form, one UTF-16 code-unit per "character".)

The bigger problem is that JavaScript doesn't support `\p{L}`, nor any equivalent notation; JavaScript regexes have no awareness of Unicode character properties. See the answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/280712/978917) for some ways to approximate it.

---

**Edited to add:** If you only need to support Polish letters, then you can write `/^[\sa-zA-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźż]+$/`. The `a-z` and `A-Z` parts cover the ASCII letters, and then the remaining letters are listed out individually.

Comment: Bad news... so maybe there is something to allow only those Polish characters: `Ł`, `Ą`, `Ś`, `Ć`, `Ę` instead?

Comment: Scott, if you have a small set of characters you want to allow you can always use a character class.

Comment: @Joey Yea, generally I would like to additionaly allow only those special characters I mentioned above.

Comment: In Javascript regexp you can refer to unicode chars like this: `\u0161`. For example this will allow only printable ASCII and Ć:
`var newtxt = txt.replace(/[^\u0107\u0020-\u007e]/g, '')` .
Unicode codes for your chars find for example here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/107/index.htm

Comment: @DamirR: What a bizarre comment. `/\u0107/` is equivalent to `/Ć/`; why on Earth would you prefer the former?

Comment: @ruakh: Life is full of bizarre moments. :) For `/Ć/` to work you MUST save js file in UTF-8. Sometimes, other people might use, change, save your code and they might use other encoding (eg. iso-8859-1). So `/Ć/` will not be saved correctly and script will not work. If you use `/\u0107/` that kind of bugs will be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

As of ES2015, */u* is supported in JavaScript. See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode
- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.unicode

Comment: It's currently not supported by all browsers.

Comment: @PoulBak It says on [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode#Browser_compatibility) it's supported by all major browsers, unless they got it wrong.

Comment: Some versions of Edge will simply crash, if you use it, but I think that has been fixed, so you're probably right (noone use IE any more).