# SCRIPT5017 error on Internet Explorer 11, using webpack 4, babel 7 and react

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, webpack-4

So I am working on a website that is using react. I have been testing it in different browsers, and right now the only browser not working is the terrible Internet Explorer. When the page loads on internet explorer it is just a blank/white screen. I have tried multiple suggestions like integrating browserlist, @babel/preset-env with no luck. I completely upgraded from babel 6 to babel 7 to see if that was the issue and nothing changed.

Here are my Dependencies and Dev Dependencies:

```
[
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.10.4",
  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.4",
  "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
  "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
  "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.8.0",
  "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.6.0",
  "axios": "^0.19.2",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
  "browser-image-compression": "^1.0.11",
  "browserslist": "^4.13.0",
  "core-js": "3.6.5",
  "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
  "emotion": "^10.0.27",
  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
  "file-system": "^2.2.2",
  "firebase": "^7.14.5",
  "firebase-functions": "^3.6.2",
  "fuse.js": "^6.4.0",
  "google-map-react": "^1.1.7",
  "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
  "img-loader": "^3.0.1",
  "jest": "^25.2.4",
  "jquery": "^3.5.1",
  "mdbreact": "^4.26.0",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "net": "^1.0.2",
  "photoeditorsdk": "^5.0.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
  "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
  "react-cookie-consent": "^5.0.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-drag-sortable": "^1.0.6",
  "react-dropzone": "^10.2.2",
  "react-facebook": "^8.1.4",
  "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
  "react-icons": "^3.9.0",
  "react-json-tree": "^0.11.2",
  "react-lazyload": "^3.0.0",
  "react-phone-input-2": "^2.13.7",
  "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.1",
  "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
  "react-router-guards": "^1.0.2",
  "react-social-icons": "^4.1.0",
  "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
  "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
  "redux": "^4.0.5",
  "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
  "stripe": "^8.76.0",
  "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
  "styled-jsx": "^3.2.5",
  "unirest": "^0.6.0",
  "url-polyfill": "^1.1.10",
  "uuidv4": "^6.0.7",
  "webworkify-webpack": "^2.1.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
  "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.10.5",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.5",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
  "babel-jest": "^25.2.4",
  "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
  "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
  "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
  "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
  "compression-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
  "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
  "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
  "eslint": "^6.8.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
  "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
  "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
  "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
  "inspectpack": "^4.5.2",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
  "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
  "prettier": "^2.0.4",
  "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.20",
  "sass": "^1.26.10",
  "sass-lint": "^1.13.1",
  "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
  "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
  "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
  "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
  "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
  "webpack": "^4.43.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
  "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
}
```

]

Here is some of my webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|webp)$/i,
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'img-loader',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    enforce: "pre",
    loader: "eslint-loader",
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    options: {
      emitWarning: true,
      configFile: "./.eslintrc.json"
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'sass-loader',
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  }
]
```

},

EDIT:
I forgot to add my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
"presets": [[
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
        "corejs": { "version": 3 },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "targets": {
            "edge": "17",
            "firefox": "60",
            "chrome": "67",
            "safari": "11.1",
            "ie": "11",
            "browsers": [
                "Chrome >= 59",
                "FireFox >= 44",
                "Safari >= 7",
                "Explorer 11",
                "ie 11",
                "last 4 Edge versions"
            ]
        }
    }
], "@babel/preset-react"],
"plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"], ["syntax-async-functions"], ["emotion"], ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "decoratorsBeforeExport": true }], ["@babel/transform-runtime"]]
```

}

Here is the error I am getting in Internet Explorer 11:[SCRIPT5017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QTYd.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent a few more hours looking at the error in Internet Explorer, finally realized that the error was coming from regex for the UUIDv4 package. The issue was unrelated to Babel as it seems I had everything setup correctly. This [Post] ([uuidv4.js regular expression issue - IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102986/uuidv4-js-regular-expression-issue-ie11)) helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Preset-env doesnt support ie 11 by default. You have to configure it as a minimum supported version. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#options

Comment: I made an edit to my original post. I forgot to add my babel.config.js

Comment: Hmm are you sure its a babel.config.js and not a .babelrc.json file? Also what doctype are you using?

Comment: Ive been able to use babel.config.js or .babelrc.json either in terms of adding plugins to babel has worked until this.

Comment: I am using <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: .babelrc.json only applies to your files so it won't compile your node_modules.  This usually means it fails for IE compatibility unless you are using a limited set of libraries.  This was a change in babel 7.x

Comment: I just changed it to .babelrc.json and recompiled in Internet Explorer 11 and I am still getting the same issue. I even deleted all the cache as a precaution.