# how to find private char utf8 in a text?

Tags: javascript, regex

In the UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters, i use the Supplementary private use area because  there are single char that i m sure they won't be used in any text.
The fact is now i need to find them in a text. Here's a basic example :

```
\u{f0001} hahrehr \u{f0002} eryteryte \u{f0003}\n yfukguk\u{f0004}\nggikggk
```

You can see that \u{f...} are my special chars.
if we console.log this text :

```js
console.log("\u{f0001} hahrehr \u{f0002} eryteryte \u{f0003}\n yfukguk\u{f0004}\nggikggk</");
```

Now i need something to find all of those special char. I thought of a regexp but I don’t know how handled the fact that \u{f...} is interpreted differently.

I know that my probleme is not very clear but i take any idea which can help me.

Comment: So you need to capture all the characters "\u{..}" with this format ?

Comment: i need to catch all to replace them after

Comment: `/\udb80\udc01/` will find it, because it's actually two ucs16 characters. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode and https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [three private use areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas):

- One in the Basic Multilingual Plane, `\uE000-\uF8FF`,
- [Plane 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Private_Use_Area_planes), `\u{F0000}-\u{FFFFD}`, and
- [Plane 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Private_Use_Area_planes), `\u{100000}-\u{10FFFD}`.

You may use

```
/[\uE000-\uF8FF\u{F0000}-\u{FFFFD}\u{100000}-\u{10FFFD}]/gu
```

to match all the occurrences of these characters with the ES6 compliant regex.

See [Regex modifier /u in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896985) to learn more about `u` modifier. Here, it is necessary to support `\u{XXXXX}` notation.

The ES5 compliant pattern is

```
/(?:[\uE000-\uF8FF]|[\uDB80-\uDBBE\uDBC0-\uDBFE][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uDBBF\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFD])/g
```

To get the array of **hex code for the code points** matched use some additional JavaScript code:

```js
const str = "\u{f0001} hahrehr \u{f0002} eryteryte \u{f0003}\n yfukguk\u{f0004}\nggikggk</";
const regex = /[\uE000-\uF8FF\u{F0000}-\u{FFFFD}\u{100000}-\u{10FFFD}]/gu;
console.log(
  str.match(regex).map(x => Array.from(x)
    .map((v) => v.codePointAt(0).toString(16))
    .map((hex) => "0000".substring(0, 4 - hex.length) + hex))
);
```

Comment: You might want to point out how the `u` flag is essential.

Comment: should .match(/[{0001}-{ffff}]/ug); works to get only number of each \u{f...} char ?

Comment: @Esposito No, you do not do that this way. If you need to get the hex codes, you will need to process matches with some additional logic.

Comment: yes i know, something like that i tried : ```var match = text.match(/[\u{10000}-\u{fffff}]/ug);```
    ```var match2 = match[0].match(/[{10000}-{fffff}]/ug);``` but once again it's not working cause he try to match with the private char and not the STRING

Comment: @Esposito You're looking for `match.map(m => m.codePointAt(0))`

Comment: I thought I could adapt your code to my use but apparently I’m not good enough at it.
I need to replace each match with its value (which is stored in a map) but I have tested several things, including this one (next comm) but it does not work. I probably don’t have the hindsight to find the solution I’ve been on for an hour.

Comment: `var map = new Map();
    map.set("&#983041;", 'something1');
    map.set("&#983042;", 'something2');
    const str = "\u{f0001} lorem ipsum \u{f0002} dolor sit amet \u{f0003}\n consectetur adipiscing elit\u{f0004}\sed do eiusmod tempor</";
    var tab = str.match(regex).map(x => Array.from(x)
            .map((v) => v.codePointAt(0).toString(10))
            .map((hex) => "0000".substring(0, 4 - hex.length) + hex))
    for(var i = 0 ; i < tab.length ; i++){
        str.replace(/[\uE000-\uF8FF\u{F0000}-\u{FFFFD}\u{100000}-\u{10FFFD}]/u, map.get("&#"+tab[i][0]+";"));
    }`

Comment: hard to understand that code, may i do something to fix indentation?

Comment: Update the question.

Comment: I just asked a new question "replace char with regexp and map - js"