# Validating UTF-8 names in JavaScript (Node.js) with XRegExp

Tags: javascript, node.js, xregexp

I'm trying to check if a given UTF-8 string consists of letters only.
I tried the solution I found here: [Validating user's UTF-8 name in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381752/validating-users-utf-8-name-in-javascript)

Given string: `Ciesiołkiewicz`
is tested with `var XRegExp = require('xregexp').XRegExp('^\\p{L}+$');`

And it's not working because of "ł" letter
I tried `XRegExp('^[\\p{Latin}\\p{Common}]+$');`
but it's too much, it accepts polish letters but also characters like "$" etc

How can I validate it against letters only? I don't want to type them into regexp manually.

Comment: Are you sure you save the script with the utf8 encoding?

Comment: that's it, file was ANSI. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var XRegExp = require('xregexp').XRegExp;
var re = new XRegExp('^\\p{L}+$');

console.log(re.test('Ciesiołkiewicz'));
console.log(re.test('1Ciesiołkiewicz2'));
console.log(re.test('привет'));
console.log(re.test('пр1вет'));

> true
> false
> true
> false
```

works perfectly.

Comment: My code wasn't wrong, I just didn't save my test's file as utf-8

Answer (score -2):

how about a character range like [a-Z]? thats what i usually use if im looking only for letters

Comment: you should read [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for example.

Comment: Hey, im sorry! I misread! was under the impression that you wanted regular characters A-Z a-z, my mistake.