# Regular expression to validate full name with email in brackets (brackets required)

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regular expression to validate a textbox input with a name and email (email is in angle brackets), i.e. `John Smith <john@smith.com>`). Unaccepted entries would be `John Smith john@smith.com`, or `"John Smith" <john@smith.com>`.

**I have looked at many threads but I don't see one that deals with requiring angle brackets <>.**

I have looked at this thread

[regular expression for email with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042544/regular-expression-for-email-with-name)

but either the information I need isn't there or I'm not able to extract the answer.  I tried the regex that's suggested in the first answer

```
^(?:(?:[a-z\d.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z\d-]+(?:\.[a-z\d-]+)*|"?([a-z]| (?! ))+"? )(?:,\s*|$))*$
```

but I don't get a match on my example text.

This textbox input would only accept one entry (name + email).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the language you're using? What did you try other than copy&paste?

Comment: While not elegant or useful, `"John Smith" <john@smith.com>` is a valid address; in fact, some software insists on putting your name in double quotes, as if it wasn't really your name. (ISTR earlier versions if Outlook had this, unsurprisingly.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract email and name with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010875/extract-email-and-name-with-regex)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate because the regex in that thread allows for this example without brackets - John Smith john@smith.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an actual attempt to answer your question, since people just seem to blindly post RFC822 regexes...

Let's start from the initial regex you provided:

```
^(?:(?:[a-z\d.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-z\d-]+(?:\.[a-z\d-]+)*|"?([a-z]| (?! ))+"? )(?:,\s*|$))*$
```

Reformat it:

```
^
(?:
  (?:
    [a-z\d.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+
    @
    [a-z\d-]+
    (?:
      \.[a-z\d-]+
    )*
  |
    "?([a-z]| (?! ))+"? 
  )
  (?:,\s*|$)
)*
$
```

Ok, so we can see it tries to match a list of addresses and names. That's not what we want. Let's extract only the address part:

```
[a-z\d.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+
@
[a-z\d-]+
(?:
  \.[a-z\d-]+
)*
```

Good, let's tweak it a bit, and add the angle brackets requirement:

```
<(
  [\w.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+
  @
  [\w-]+
  (?:
    \.[\w-]+
  )+
)>
```

Now, just match a name in front of it. Let's assume a name can contain anything.

```
^
\s*
(.+?)
\s*
<(
  [\w.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+
  @
  [\w-]+
  (?:
    \.[\w-]+
  )+
)>
\s*
$
```

Here. that looks nice: [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gC7wJ1/2). The name is in the first group, the address is in the second group.

Short version:

```
^\s*(.+?)\s*<([\w.!#$%&’*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)>\s*$
```

If you want to be more restrictive, you can limit the allowed characters in names, let's only allow letters, digits and spaces:

```
^
\s*
([\p{L}\d\s]+?)
\s*
<(
  [\w.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+
  @
  [\w-]+
  (?:
    \.[\w-]+
  )+
)>
\s*
$
```

This eliminates the quoted name case: [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gC7wJ1/3).

Short version:

```
^\s*([\p{L}\d\s]+?)\s*<([\w.!#$%&’*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)>\s*$
```

Comment: Wow, that was exactly what I was looking for...that answer not only solves my problem but sheds some light on how you got to the solution! Thank you! So awesome!

Comment: Validating empty space in the name part i-e ` <john@smith.com>` is valid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate an email accordingly to the [RFC822](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/), this is the regex :

```
(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ 
\t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\0
31]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\
](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+
(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:
(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\
r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)
*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+
|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r
\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031
]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?
:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?
:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?
:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?
[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|
\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>
@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"
(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?
:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[
\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-
\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;
:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([
^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"
.\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\
]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\
[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\
r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]
|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \0
00-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\
.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,
;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?
:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[
^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]
]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:,\s*(
?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[
\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?
:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|
\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:
[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\
]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["
()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>
@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,
;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[
"()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\
.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)?;\s*)
```

But better use a module ;)

See http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: Oh come on, that's from old times when recursion was unavailable.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski The "regular" in "regular expression" rules out recursion. Pattern matching languages with recursion aren't regular expressions.

Comment: @Kaz Yes I know that very well, but almost all "regex" tools available today go further than regular languages. The "regex" part is mostly historic. Why limit yourself?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Why limit yourself: because proper regular expressions specify finite-state automatons, which can be compiled to achieve blindingly fast performance. The finite automaton is a useful class of object from a practical, not only theoretical perspective.

Comment: @Kaz I agree that you should use regular constructs when you want to match a regular language. But when you want to match a *simple* context-free language that a modern pattern-matching library can handle, I don't see a reason not to do so (unless you have a real parser of course). If I had to choose between a non-regular one-liner and a 6KB regular pattern which doesn't even handle the general case (see Friedl's book, 2nd edition, as this pattern is most probably from there), I wouldn't hesitate.

Comment: If I copy and paste this into regex101.com (after removing cr and lf), it tells me there is an error in the expression?

Comment: @sds - The regex parses ok, something wrong with regex101.com. Or, remove all the `\r`'s, or replace with `\r?`.

Comment: Anyway the above regex would benefit not from recursion, but from macro-substitution. For instance, in the Unix utility Lex, we can define named regular expression fragments, and then use them by name. The names are simply replaced by the fragment they denote.

Comment: This regex can definitely be refactored.

Comment: @sln - When I do that (replace \r with \r? I still get an error.

Comment: @Kaz Yes, it could benefit from the `(?(DEFINE) ... )` Perl/PCRE construct :) Joking aside, the problem is that RFC822 defines comments in email addresses as text between parentheses. The catch is that these comments can be nested, hence the need for recursion. IIRC Friedl generated the pattern used in this answer in his book at a time when recursion wasn't implemented in Perl, and made it handle 3 or 4 nesting levels. More levels could be added simply by changing a variable in the generator at the cost of pattern size.

Answer (score 0):

Validate an email accordingly to the RFC822:

@sputnick 's regex formatted.

```
(?x)
(?:
    (?: \r \n )?
    [ \t] 
)*
(?:
    (?:
        (?:
            [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
            (?:
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )+
              | \Z 
              | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
            )
          | "
            (?:
                [^\"\r\\] 
              | \\ . 
              | (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )
            )*
            "
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
        )
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | "
                (?:
                    [^\"\r\\] 
                  | \\ . 
                  | (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )
                )*
                "
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
        )*
        @
        (?:
            (?: \r \n )?
            [ \t] 
        )*
        (?:
            [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
            (?:
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )+
              | \Z 
              | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
            )
          | \[
            ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
            \]
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
        )
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | \[
                ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                \]
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
        )*
      | (?:
            [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
            (?:
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )+
              | \Z 
              | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
            )
          | "
            (?:
                [^\"\r\\] 
              | \\ . 
              | (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )
            )*
            "
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
        )*
        \<
        (?:
            (?: \r \n )?
            [ \t] 
        )*
        (?:
            @
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | \[
                ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                \]
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
            (?:
                \.
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | \[
                    ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                    \]
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
            )*
            (?:
                ,@
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | \[
                    ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                    \]
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
                (?:
                    \.
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                    (?:
                        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                        (?:
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )+
                          | \Z 
                          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                        )
                      | \[
                        ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                        \]
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                    )
                )*
            )*
            :
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
        )?
        (?:
            [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
            (?:
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )+
              | \Z 
              | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
            )
          | "
            (?:
                [^\"\r\\] 
              | \\ . 
              | (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )
            )*
            "
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
        )
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | "
                (?:
                    [^\"\r\\] 
                  | \\ . 
                  | (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )
                )*
                "
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
        )*
        @
        (?:
            (?: \r \n )?
            [ \t] 
        )*
        (?:
            [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
            (?:
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )+
              | \Z 
              | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
            )
          | \[
            ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
            \]
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
        )
        (?:
            \.
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | \[
                ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                \]
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
        )*
        \>
        (?:
            (?: \r \n )?
            [ \t] 
        )*
    )
  | (?:
        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
        (?:
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )+
          | \Z 
          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
        )
      | "
        (?:
            [^\"\r\\] 
          | \\ . 
          | (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )
        )*
        "
        (?:
            (?: \r \n )?
            [ \t] 
        )*
    )*
    :
    (?:
        (?: \r \n )?
        [ \t] 
    )*
    (?:
        (?:
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | "
                (?:
                    [^\"\r\\] 
                  | \\ . 
                  | (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )
                )*
                "
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
            (?:
                \.
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | "
                    (?:
                        [^\"\r\\] 
                      | \\ . 
                      | (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )
                    )*
                    "
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
            )*
            @
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | \[
                ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                \]
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
            (?:
                \.
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | \[
                    ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                    \]
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
            )*
          | (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | "
                (?:
                    [^\"\r\\] 
                  | \\ . 
                  | (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )
                )*
                "
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )*
            \<
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
            (?:
                @
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | \[
                    ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                    \]
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
                (?:
                    \.
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                    (?:
                        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                        (?:
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )+
                          | \Z 
                          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                        )
                      | \[
                        ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                        \]
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                    )
                )*
                (?:
                    ,@
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                    (?:
                        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                        (?:
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )+
                          | \Z 
                          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                        )
                      | \[
                        ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                        \]
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                    )
                    (?:
                        \.
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                        (?:
                            [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                            (?:
                                (?:
                                    (?: \r \n )?
                                    [ \t] 
                                )+
                              | \Z 
                              | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                            )
                          | \[
                            ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                            \]
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )*
                        )
                    )*
                )*
                :
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )?
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | "
                (?:
                    [^\"\r\\] 
                  | \\ . 
                  | (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )
                )*
                "
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
            (?:
                \.
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | "
                    (?:
                        [^\"\r\\] 
                      | \\ . 
                      | (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )
                    )*
                    "
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
            )*
            @
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
            (?:
                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                (?:
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )+
                  | \Z 
                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                )
              | \[
                ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                \]
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
            (?:
                \.
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | \[
                    ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                    \]
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
            )*
            \>
            (?:
                (?: \r \n )?
                [ \t] 
            )*
        )
        (?:
            , \s* 
            (?:
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | "
                    (?:
                        [^\"\r\\] 
                      | \\ . 
                      | (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )
                    )*
                    "
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
                (?:
                    \.
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                    (?:
                        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                        (?:
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )+
                          | \Z 
                          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                        )
                      | "
                        (?:
                            [^\"\r\\] 
                          | \\ . 
                          | (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )
                        )*
                        "
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                    )
                )*
                @
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | \[
                    ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                    \]
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
                (?:
                    \.
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                    (?:
                        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                        (?:
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )+
                          | \Z 
                          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                        )
                      | \[
                        ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                        \]
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                    )
                )*
              | (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | "
                    (?:
                        [^\"\r\\] 
                      | \\ . 
                      | (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )
                    )*
                    "
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )*
                \<
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    @
                    (?:
                        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                        (?:
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )+
                          | \Z 
                          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                        )
                      | \[
                        ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                        \]
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                    )
                    (?:
                        \.
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                        (?:
                            [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                            (?:
                                (?:
                                    (?: \r \n )?
                                    [ \t] 
                                )+
                              | \Z 
                              | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                            )
                          | \[
                            ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                            \]
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )*
                        )
                    )*
                    (?:
                        ,@
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                        (?:
                            [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                            (?:
                                (?:
                                    (?: \r \n )?
                                    [ \t] 
                                )+
                              | \Z 
                              | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                            )
                          | \[
                            ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                            \]
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )*
                        )
                        (?:
                            \.
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )*
                            (?:
                                [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                                (?:
                                    (?:
                                        (?: \r \n )?
                                        [ \t] 
                                    )+
                                  | \Z 
                                  | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                                )
                              | \[
                                ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                                \]
                                (?:
                                    (?: \r \n )?
                                    [ \t] 
                                )*
                            )
                        )*
                    )*
                    :
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )?
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | "
                    (?:
                        [^\"\r\\] 
                      | \\ . 
                      | (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )
                    )*
                    "
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
                (?:
                    \.
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                    (?:
                        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                        (?:
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )+
                          | \Z 
                          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                        )
                      | "
                        (?:
                            [^\"\r\\] 
                          | \\ . 
                          | (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )
                        )*
                        "
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                    )
                )*
                @
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
                (?:
                    [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                    (?:
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )+
                      | \Z 
                      | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                    )
                  | \[
                    ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                    \]
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                )
                (?:
                    \.
                    (?:
                        (?: \r \n )?
                        [ \t] 
                    )*
                    (?:
                        [^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+ 
                        (?:
                            (?:
                                (?: \r \n )?
                                [ \t] 
                            )+
                          | \Z 
                          | (?= [\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]] )
                        )
                      | \[
                        ( [^\[\]\r\\] | \\ . )*
                        \]
                        (?:
                            (?: \r \n )?
                            [ \t] 
                        )*
                    )
                )*
                \>
                (?:
                    (?: \r \n )?
                    [ \t] 
                )*
            )
        )*
    )?
    ; \s* 
)
```