# Check if string contain only utf8 letter

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

I've been searching for a method to deal with this stuff in Javascript.

PHP has a library that handles unicode character, which called [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). Base on these patterns, UTF-8 letters can be found via something like `preg_match('/^\p{L}+/u', $string)`.

How could I do this in JS?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381752/validating-users-utf-8-name-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript's only unicode feature is that it lets you match one characters with `\uDDDD`, so if you need `\P{L}`, no luck.

However, Steven Levithan, co-author of the excellent *Regular Expressions Cookbook* (together with regex guru Jan Goyvaert), has an alternate library called [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) that has many more features, including those you seek. You can test it both in RegexBuddy (a standalone app by Jan) and in [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/).

Quoting from the doc:

> XRegExp supports matching Unicode categories, scripts, blocks, and
>   other properties via addon scripts. Such tokens are matched using
>   \p{…}, \P{…}, and \p{^…}.

See [XRegExp Unicode add-ons](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode).