# how can use utf 8 characters on jquery form validation Guardian plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, utf-8

I want to use jQuery Guardian plugin for validation form but when I use utf 8 characters I am not able to submit the form and I have validation error. Now How can I use form validation Guardian plugin with utf 8 character?
example:

```
  <form action="" id="sample" name="sample">
   <input type="text" name="name" data-error-message="Name is Required!" required="required"/>
   <input type="submit" value="send"/>
```

```
$('#sample').guardian();
```

when using `utf8` character I have this error: Name is Required!

`Utf8` characters are not working on demo site either
Docs:
http://jquery.michaeleisenbraun.com/guardian/docs/
demo: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?YMeYXifw

Comment: You cant, the regx of guardian plugin doenst accept special characters

Comment: How can change it regex?

Comment: just create a validation for character limit, like max letters 25 but if you want check the regx you can start reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381752/validating-users-utf-8-name-in-javascript