# Java regex doesnt match outside of ascii range, behaves different than python regex

Tags: java, regex, scikit-learn, pattern-matching, countvectorizer

I want to filter Strings from documents the same way sklearn's [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html%22CountVectorizer%22) does. It uses the following RegEx: `(?u)\b\w\w+\b`.
This java code should behave the same way:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("this is the document.!? äöa m²");

while(matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

But this doesnt produce the desired output, as it does in python:

```
this
is
the
document
äöa
m²
```

It instead outputs:

```
this
is
the
document
```

What can i do to include non-ascii characters, as the python RegeEx does?

Comment: Try `"(?U)\\b\\w\\w+\\b"` or just `"(?U)\\w{2,}"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that does work for `äöa` but doesn't work for `m²`

Comment: MAybe this is useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381752/validating-users-utf-8-name-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you! This works for the german letters, but still doesnt include the squared sign (²), any idea how to fix that one?

Comment: @LanceToth i am working with Java, not JavaScript

Comment: Do you want to make sure the Unicode `\w` in Java regex matches the same chars as Python's Unicode `\w`?

Comment: @DanielKirchner sorry, misread

Comment: Ok, same thing, but for Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exactly, i have a pretty big document file i am testing this with, the only difference at this point (between python and java) is that python picks up `²,½,³`.

Comment: @LanceToth it is working for unicode now with `(?U)`, only missing exponentials and fractions now.

Comment: To just support super/subscript numbers, you may extend the pattern to `"(?U)[\\w\\p{No}]{2,}"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much, this seems to be working!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode equivalents for \w and \b in Java regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions)

Comment: No, that is not the dupe, but quite helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Wiktor in the comments, you could use `(?U)` to turn on the flag `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`. While this does allow matching `äöa`, this still doesn't match `m²`. That's because `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` with `\w` doesn't recognize `²` as a valid alphanumeric character. As a replacement for `\w`, you can use `[\pN\pL_]`. This matches Unicode numbers `\pN` and Unicode letters `\pL` (plus `_`). The `\pN` Unicode character class includes the `\pNo` character class, which includes the *Latin 1 Supplement - Latin-1 punctuation and symbols* character class (it includes `²³¹`). Alternatively, you could just add the `\pNo` Unicode character class to a character class with `\w`. This means the following regular expressions correctly match your strings:

```
[\pN\pL_]{2,}         # Matches any Unicode number or letter, and underscore
(?U)[\w\pNo]{2,}      # Uses UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS so that \w matches Unicode.
                      # Adds \pNo to additionally match ²³¹
```

So why doesn't `\w` match `²` in Java but it does in Python?

---

### Java's interpretation

Looking at [OpenJDK 8-b132's `Pattern` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/regex/Pattern.java), we get the following information (I removed information irrelevant to answering the question):

> ### Unicode support
>
> The following **Predefined Character classes** and **POSIX character
>   classes** are in conformance with the recommendation of *Annex C:
>   Compatibility Properties* of *Unicode Regular Expression*, when
>   `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag is specified.
>
> `\w`  A word character: `[\p{Alpha}\p{gc=Mn}\p{gc=Me}\p{gc=Mc}\p{Digit}\p{gc=Pc}\p{IsJoin_Control}]`

Great! Now we have a *definition* for `\w` when the `(?U)` flag is used. Plugging these Unicode character classes into [this amazing tool](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp) will tell you exactly what each of these Unicode character classes match. Without making this post super long, I'll just go ahead and tell you that neither of the following classes matches `²`:

- `\p{Alpha}`
- `\p{gc=Mn}`
- `\p{gc=Me}`
- `\p{gc=Mc}`
- `\p{Digit}`
- `\p{gc=Pc}`
- `\p{IsJoin_Control}`

---

### Python's interpretation

So why does Python match `²³¹` when the `u` flag is used in conjunction with `\w`? This one was very difficult to track down, but I went digging into [Python's source code (I used Python 3.6.5rc1 - 2018-03-13)](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/). After removing a lot of the fluff for how this gets called, basically the following happens:

- `\w` is defined as `CATEGORY_UNI_WORD`, which is then prefixed with `SRE_`. `SRE_CATEGORY_UNI_WORD` calls `SRE_UNI_IS_WORD(ch)`
- `SRE_UNI_IS_WORD` is defined as `(SRE_UNI_IS_ALNUM(ch) || (ch) == '_')`.
- `SRE_UNI_IS_ALNUM` calls `Py_UNICODE_ISALNUM`, which is, in turn, defined as `(Py_UNICODE_ISALPHA(ch) || Py_UNICODE_ISDECIMAL(ch) || Py_UNICODE_ISDIGIT(ch) || Py_UNICODE_ISNUMERIC(ch))`.
- The important one here is `Py_UNICODE_ISDECIMAL(ch)`, defined as `Py_UNICODE_ISDECIMAL(ch) _PyUnicode_IsDecimalDigit(ch)`.

Now, let's take a look at the method `_PyUnicode_IsDecimalDigit(ch)`:

```
int _PyUnicode_IsDecimalDigit(Py_UCS4 ch)
{
    if (_PyUnicode_ToDecimalDigit(ch) < 0)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

As we can see, this method returns `1` if `_PyUnicode_ToDecimalDigit(ch) < 0`. So what does `_PyUnicode_ToDecimalDigit` look like?

```
int _PyUnicode_ToDecimalDigit(Py_UCS4 ch)
{
    const _PyUnicode_TypeRecord *ctype = gettyperecord(ch);

    return (ctype->flags & DECIMAL_MASK) ? ctype->decimal : -1;
}
```

Great, so basically, if the character's UTF-32 encoded byte has the `DECIMAL_MASK` flag this will evaluate to true and a value greater than or equal to `0` will be returned.

UTF-32 encoded byte value for `²` is `0x000000b2` and our flag `DECIMAL_MASK` is `0x02`. `0x000000b2 & 0x02` evaluates to true and so `²` is deemed to be a valid Unicode alphanumeric character in python, thus `\w` with `u` flag matches `²`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more step left: you need to specify that `\w` includes unicode characters too. `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` for the rescue:

```
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
                                                   // ^^^^^^^^^^
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("this is the document.!? äöa m²");

    while(matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(match);
    }
```