# Java regex error

Tags: java, regex

Whenever I enter the following...

```
Pattern pmessage = Pattern.compile("\s*\p{Alnum}[\p{Alnum}\s]*");
Matcher mmessage = pmessage.matcher(message);
Matcher msubject = pmessage.matcher(subject);
```

I get a `Invalid Escape Sequence` error. Anyone have any idea why / how I fix this?

Comment: Be warned that even corrected for ddoouubbllee bbaacckkssllllaasshheess, that doesn’t work with Java native characters, only with ASCII.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `bbaacckkssllaasshheess` instead of `bbaacckkssllllaasshheess`? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a version of `\p{Alpha}` that works on the Java native character set instead being stuck unsable to process anything else than legacy data from the 1960s, you need to use

```
alphabetics = "[\\pL\\pM\\p{Nl]";
```

For a version of numerics in the same sense, you have to choose which of these you want:

```
ASCII_digits    = "[0-9]";
all_numbers     = "\\pN";
decimal_numbers = "\\p{Nd}"
```

because which one applies various depending on circumstances.  We’ll assume you copied one of those three to a `numeric` variable.

Assuming you then want alphanumerics based on the definition above, you could then write:

```
 alphanumerics = "[" + alphabetics + numerics + "]";
```

However, if what you mean by alphanumerics is the `\w` sense of program identifiers, you have to add some stuff.

```
 identifier_chars = "[\\pL\\pM\\p{Nd}\\p{Nl}\\p{Pc}[\\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\\p{So}]]";
```

This issue is discussed at length in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261), where you’ll also find a link to some alpha code of mine that does these transforms for you automatically.  I hope to get a chance to rewrite it to take up less space this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Double each backslash: `Pattern.compile("\\s*\\p{Alnum}[\\p{Alnum}\\s]*")`

Backslashes inside string literals have a [special meaning](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#101089), and have to be duplicated in order for the actual backslash character to become part of the string (which is what is required in your regex example.)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, that backslashes are special characters in Java strings, that need to be escaped with an additional backslash:

```
Pattern.compile("\\s*\\p{Alnum}[\\p{Alnum}\\s]*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't correctly escape your "\" characters : in java, "\s" will give you \s, so you should write :

```
Pattern.compile("\\s*\\p{Alnum}[\\p{Alnum}\\s]*");
```