# Subtract from character class

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to subtract characters or a character range from another character class?

I need to find a substring within a string, which should only contain characters, but without "<" and ">".

```
[[:print:]] - ('<' | '>')
```

Its because "<" and ">" are delimiters and should not occur within the string itself.

```
<abc> // valid
<ab<c> // invalid
<ab\tc> //invalid
```

Comment: ... Are you trying to parse HTML with a regex?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You want to remove the `<` and `>` characters, or you want to remove any string that looks like `<example>`?

Comment: If you want to know: I want to parse NTriples files ( http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/ ), wich also answers to the second question. I want to get the three parts of the triple. Maybe I solve it another way (split at CR, LF, or CRLF), but it would be cool, if somebody can solve the problem anyway, because in the past sometimes I missed something also.

Comment: What functions do you use? Those using [POSIX ERE](http://php.net/book.regex) or [PCRE](http://php.net/book.pcre)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[:print:]` is equivalent to `[\x20-\x7E]` so if you don't want `<` (`\x3C`) and `>` (`\x3E`), you can do `[\x20-\x3B\x3D\x3F-\x7E]`

this will match printable characters in a string except `<` and `>`

```
/[\x20-\x3B\x3D\x3F-\x7E]+/
```

Comment: I suspect it ... So there is really no more readable/easier way to express something like `a-z without x`?

Comment: You can use the chars themselves as `[ -;=?-~]`

Answer (score 3):

In regular expressions, you can easily do union, intersection, and subtraction of character classes.

```
[a[b]]
```

is the union.

```
[a&&b]
```

is the intersection.

```
[a&&[^b]]
```

is the subtraction.

I regularly do [rather complex set operations in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261). For example, this is what you have to use in Java

```
[^\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]]
```

for a modern version of `\w`.  (You don’t have to do that in Perl, since `\w` isn’t broken there the way it is in Java.) Word boundaries get a tad harder:

```
(?:(?<=[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])(?![\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])|(?<![\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])(?=[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]]))
```

But at least now you have a `\b` that works in Java, not a broken thing that screws up everything you do. To implement `\X` in languages that don’t have it, you can either use a *legacy grapheme cluster*, defined as:

```
(?>\PM\pM*)
```

Or you can use an *extended grapheme cluster*, defined as (or nearly as, actually):

```
(?:(?:\u000D\u000A)|(?:[\u0E40\u0E41\u0E42\u0E43\u0E44\u0EC0\u0EC1\u0EC2\u0EC3\u0EC4\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9\uAABB\uAABC]*(?:[\u1100-\u115F\uA960-\uA97C]+|([\u1100-\u115F\uA960-\uA97C]*((?:[[\u1160-\u11A2\uD7B0-\uD7C6][\uAC00\uAC1C\uAC38]][\u1160-\u11A2\uD7B0-\uD7C6]*|[\uAC01\uAC02\uAC03\uAC04])[\u11A8-\u11F9\uD7CB-\uD7FB]*))|[\u11A8-\u11F9\uD7CB-\uD7FB]+|[^[\p{Zl}\p{Zp}\p{Cc}\p{Cf}&&[^\u000D\u000A\u200C\u200D]]\u000D\u000A])[[\p{Mn}\p{Me}\u200C\u200D\u0488\u0489\u20DD\u20DE\u20DF\u20E0\u20E2\u20E3\u20E4\uA670\uA671\uA672\uFF9E\uFF9F][\p{Mc}\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E45\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3]]*)|(?s:.))
```

Of course, you don’t have to go through such extreme rewrites if you happen to be using a language with the **radical notion of actually  supporting  *their own native* character set!**

Unfortunately, Java is not one of those.

For regexes, I suggest using something more modern, like Perl, Python, or Ruby. Because otherwise you’re stuck in the Stone Age.