# Unicode regexp to match line-breaks?

Tags: regex, unicode, character-properties, line-breaks

I have this form from where I want to submit data to a database. The data is UTF8. I am having trouble with matching line breaks. The pattern I am using is something like this:

```
~^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N} ]+$~u
```

This pattern works fine until the user puts a new line in his text box. I have tried using `\p{Z}` inside the class but with no success. I also tried "s" but it didn’t work.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A Unicode linebreak is either a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed, or else it is any character with the vertical whitespace property.

But it looks like you’re trying to match generic whitespace there.  In Java, that would be

```
 [\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]
```

which can be shortened by using ranges to “only” this:

```
 [\u000A-\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]
```

to include both horizontal whitespace (`\h`) and vertical whitespace (`\v`), which may or may not be the same as general whitespace (`\s`).

It also looks like you’re trying to match alphanumerics.

- Alphabetics alone are usually `[\pL\pM\p{Nl}]`.
- Numerics are not so often all `\pN` as often as they are either just `\p{Nd}` or else sometimes `[\p{Nd}\p{Nl}]`.
- Identifer characters need connector punctuation and a bit more, so `[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]]` — if your regex engine supports those sorts of operations (Java’s does).  That’s what `\w` works out to in Unicode-aware regex languages (of which Java is not one).

In older versions of Perl, you would likely write a linebreak as

```
 (?:\r\n|\p{VertSpace})
```

although that’s now better written as

```
 (?:(?>\r\n)|\v)
```

which is exactly what

```
 \R
```

matches.

Java is very clumsy at these things.  There you must write a linebreak as

```
  (?:(?>\u000D\u000A)|[\u000A-\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])
```

which of course requires extra bbaacckkssllasshheess when written as a string.

The other Java equivalences for the 14 common character-class regex escapes so that they work with Unicode I give [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261). You may have to use those in other Java-like regex languages that aren’t sufficiently Unicode-aware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well this is actually for a "comments" form. Users write their comments there and they are stored to the DB. The problem was that when i tried to change line with "enter" the regex would not match. But it does now! :)