# A question on swapping XML attributes within a tag in Java

Tags: java

the question sounds a bit confusing, but it is actually straightforward. This is a follow-up of my previous post:

[Need a little help on this regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454851/need-a-little-help-on-this-regular-expression)

after successful transformation of the String, now the String looks like:

```
<media id="pc011018" rights="licensed"
        type="photo">
        <title>Sri Lankans harvest tea</title>
```

Now the only task left is to swap the three attributes of media node, so the output String should be:

```
<media type="photo" id="pc011018" rights="licensed">
        <title>Sri Lankans harvest tea</title>
```

I actually could think of a way of doing this: first of all, I extract the string enclosed by the first pair of "[" bracket. Then for this string, I will use a StringTokenizer to tokenize three attributes strings: type, id, rights; then rearrange them in a StringBuffer,turn it back into a string, then finally concatenate with the remaining [title] substring.

I am just wondering if there is a better and more efficient way rather than using StringToknizer? Please kindly help, thanks.

Comment: If you want to show literal text, indent it 4 spaces or use the 101010 button in the editor.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: If this is XML, then the order of the attributes shouldn't matter to any downstream XML processor.  Why do you need them to be in a certain order?  Also, it sounds like you really need to be using XSLT instead of regexes to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real hacky way of doing this

```
    String input="<media id=\"pc011018\" rights=\"licensed\" type=\"photo\"><title>Sri Lankans harvest tea</title></media>";
    Pattern r= Pattern.compile("<media id=\"(.*)\" rights=\"(.*)\" type=\"(.*)\">(.*)");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
    m.find();
    System.out.println("<media type=\""+m.group(3)+ "\" + id=\""+ m.group(1) + "\" rights=\"" + m.group(2) + "\">"+m.group(4));
```

Will only work if the data is always as you describe