# How do you read a certain number of characters in a file?

Tags: java

For example, there's an extremely long chain of characters in a txt file and you wish to iterate through it to find a word or integer combination, analogous to a word search.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I won't post an example because you didn't even try. However you should research regular expressions.

[Java regular expression match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463867/java-regular-expression-match)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm