# If the first name, last name and the nick name starts with the special chars

Tags: java, android

If the first name, last name and the nick name starts with the special chars like !@#$%^&*()_+?></ then show the error message like this "Enter valid first name/ last name/nick name"

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: use regex for validation

Comment: First and foremost stackoverflow isn't the place where someone will solve the entire problem for you. You need to show us the code and pinpoint the place when you encountere a problem.

Comment: Wecome to StackOverflow. How to ask a good question -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regular expression match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463867/java-regular-expression-match)

Comment: `if (name.matches("(?:!|@|#|\\$|%|\\^|&|\\*|\\(|\\)|_|\\+|\\?|>|<).*")) { System.out.println("Enter valid name"); }`

Comment: why people downvoting this. I think he asked a nice question and if it is not a duplicate then whats the issue?

Comment: @Ankush Bist  Question might be nice! But there is a way to ask! He has not shown any attempts that he made or any related thing and of course there are many smiler questions here at SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String#matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) to check if a name begins with any of the special characters on your blacklist:

```
if (name.matches("(?:!|@|#|\\$|%|\\^|&|\\*|\\(|\\)|_|\\+|\\?|>|‌​<).*")) {
    System.out.println("Enter valid name");
}
```

Another way:

```
String specialChars = "!@#$%^&*()_+?><";
if (specialChars.indexOf(name.charAt(0)) != -1) {
    System.out.println("Enter valid name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
String regex = "!@#$%^&*()_+?></ *";

if (regex.contains(firstname.charAt(0))){
   //--- set error
}
```

Comment: Thank you it work for me