# regex program alteration excluding whitespace

Tags: java, regex

I have a statement which finds strings that contain one character, say P. This works when matching against a string delimited by no white space

e.g.

```
APAXA
```

Thr regex being `^[^P]*P[^P]*$`

It picks this string out fine, however, what if I have a string

```
XPA  DREP EDS
```

What would be the regex to identify all strings in one line that match the condition (strings always seperated by some kind of white space - tab, space etc)?

e.g. how would I highlight XPA and DREP

I am using `while(m.find())` to loop multiple times and System.out.println(m.group())

so m.group has to contain the entire string.

Comment: What type of data is this?  Just uppercase ASCII letters and ASCII spaces only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it by whitespace and then check each token against your existing regex.

Comment: That won't find `DREP` as the whitespace is part of the match condition.

Answer (score 1):

why must it be a an overly complicated regex?

```
String string = "XPA  DREP EDS";
String[] s = string.split("\\s+");
for( String str: s){
  if ( str.contains("P") ){
     System.out.println( str );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try and use the `\s` pattern (match whitespace).  Look at this [regexp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) page for java.

Comment: You mean match ASCII whitespace, as opposed to Unicode whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b[^P\s]*P[^P\s]*\b
```

will match all words that contain exactly one P. Don't forget to double the backslashes when constructing your regex from a Java string.

**Explanation:**

```
\b      # Assert position at start/end of a word
[^P\s]* # Match any number of characters except P and whitespace
P       # Match a P
[^P\s]* # Match any number of characters except P and whitespace
\b      # Assert position at start/end of a word
```

Please note that `\b` doesn't match all word boundaries correctly when dealing with Unicode string (thanks tchrist for reminding me). If that is the case for you, you might want to replace the `\b`s with (don't look):

```
(?:(?<=[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])(?![\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])|(?<![\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])(?=[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]]))
```

(taken from [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions) winning answer)

Comment: It does here. It *is* supposed to match that word, isn't it?

Comment: Ah - you want the entire word to contain only one P? I get it.

Comment: No its supposed to match any word containing a single P. Sorry maybe I didn't mention that... :S

Comment: That’s another ASCII-only pattern.  It does not work “properly” on full Unicode, Java’s native character set. I strongly suggest some sort of commenting about that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

> Thr reex being ^[^P]P[^P]$

Such a regex finds only string containing exactly one P, which may or may not be what you want. I suppose you want `.*P.*` instead.

For finding all words containing *at least one* P you can use `\\S+P\\S+`, where `\S` stands for non-blank character. You may consider `\w` instead.

For finding all words containing *exactly one* P you can use `[^\\sP]+P[^\\sP]+(?=\\s)` which is more complicated. Here, `\s` stands for blank, `[^abc]` matches everything expect for abc, `(?=...)` is lookahead. Without the lookahead, you'd find in "APBPC" two "words": "APB" and "PC".

Comment: You're wrong, or do you really mean the following is ascii?  
final String s = "Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+l\\S+");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding whitespace characters (`\s`) in your negated character classes, and you'll also want to remove the `^` and `$` anchors:

```
[^P\s]*P[^P\s]*
```

or as a Java String literal:

```
"[^P\\s]*P[^P\\s]*"
```

Note that the above does **not** work on Unicode, only ASCII (as tchrist mentioned in the comments).

Comment: With the proviso that that’s only going to work on ASCII characters, not non-ASCII Unicode characters.