# RegEx to match strings that have only one C

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for some *tips* on how I can take a string like:

```
KIGABCCA TQABCCAXT
GABCCASZYU GZTTABCCA    MHNBABCCA   CLZGABCA    ABCCALZH
ABCCADQRNS VIZABCCA GABCCAG
UEKABCCA KBTOABCCA  GABCCAMFFJ  HABCCAISOJ  OFJJABCCA   HPABCCA
WBXRABCCA
ABCCAKH
VABCCAJX WBDOABCCA ABCCAWM GCABCA   QHRABCCA
ABCCAMDDD   WPABCCAD    OGABCCA
TVABCCA JGLABCA
IUABCCA
```

and to return any entire string with only one C in it.

**PLEASE NOTE: I AM NOT LOOKING FOR A SOLUTION!**

Just some pointers or a description of the sort of constructs I should be looking at.

I have been labouring over it for ages, and have come close to hurting someone because of this. It is a homework question and I'm not looking to cheat, just some guidance.

**I have read extensively about Reg Ex and I understand them.**

I'm not looking for a beginners guide.

Comment: Is this one big string with whitespaces?

Comment: That's correct.The solution should return the character string with no whitespace.

Comment: Did your teacher(?) ask you to perform this with RegEx exclusively? If so, what platform?

Comment: This looks like homework, this is a sort of duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747980/regex-program-alteration-excluding-whitespace

Comment: @maaartinus he said this is homework.

Comment: @maaa, if you read the question he states that it is indeed homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to first put a word boundary at the start and end. Then match any character that isn't C or a word boundary 0 or more times, then a C, then again, any character that isn't a C or word boundary 0 or more times. So it'll match a C on it's own, or a C with any non-C characters either (or both) side of it.

The no-C or word boundary you could do in two ways... say "any character that isn't a C or word boundary" or you could say "I want A, B or anything from D-Z". Up to you.

Comment: OP states that he doesn't want the solution, but some guidance and a description of the constructs he needs. You've solved the problem for him.

Comment: I am using `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\b[^C\b]*C[^C\b]*\b"); Matcher m = p.matcher(data);` ... But it appears to be empty of groups.

Comment: Apologies for posting "solution". I assumed when I posted that it was incomplete and there was something I haven't thought of, but actually, it did seem pretty complete. I edited hoping that @AlexW didn't see the original, but he got in there with a reply while I was editing.

Comment: @AlexW, try second option for "no C or word boundary", and take out all the \bs because they won't be needed anymore.

Comment: Inside a character class, `\b` matches a backspace character.  Not that anyone would ever want to match a backspace, but it can't perform its usual role because a word boundary is a zero-width assertion, and a character class always matches exactly one character.  I think what you're trying for is `[^C\W]*` -- not a `C` and not a non-word character.

Comment: @Alan Moore - I am now using `\\b[^C\\w]*C[^C\\w]*\\b` .. surely I want any word character except C? This is not working : (

Comment: That won't work. It doesn't allow C or any word character (of which C is one, making the C redundant) I'd make it what Alan suggested.

Comment: I'm now using `\\b[ABD-Z]*C[ABD-Z]*\\b` .. still nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Search for a pattern that has the following elements, in order:

1. The beginning of the string or any whitespace.
2. Zero or more non-whitespace non-C characters.
3. A "C"
4. Zero or more non-whitespace non-C characters.
5. The end of the string or any whitespace.

Comment: Y'know, I've ried this... and it works in principle, but in practice I've had problems... Thanks for the tips

Comment: @AlexW, the actual regex (as a Java string literal) would be `"(\\A|\\s)[^C\\s]*C[^C\\s]*(\\s|\\z)"` -- is that what you tried?  And are you using the `find()` method to apply the regex?

Comment: @Alan - I've got it sorted now, based on the tips from SO. Am now using find() too. Appreciate it.  Please leave an answer and I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a count function. then pass each string to it. just an example

```
String string = "KIGABCCA"
public static boolean countChar(String string, char ch){
     int count =0;
     for(int i = 0; i<string.length();i++){
        if(string.charAt(i) == ch ){
          count++;
        }
     }
     if ( count == 1){ 
       return true;
     }else {
       return false;
     }
}
```