# Matching (e.g.) a Unicode letter with Java regexps

Tags: java, regex, unicode, character-properties, character-class

There are many questions and answers here on StackOverflow that assume a "letter" can be matched in a regexp by `[a-zA-Z]`. However with Unicode there are many more characters that most people would regard as a letter (all the Greek letters, Cyrllic .. and many more. [Unicode defines many blocks](http://www.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/Blocks-3.txt) each of which may have "letters".

The Java definition [defines Posix classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  for things like alpha characters, but that is specified to only work with US-ASCII. The predefined character classes define words to consist of `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, which also excludes many letters.

So how do you properly match against Unicode strings? Is there some other library that gets this right?

Comment: This might help as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions

Comment: @spinning_plate, thanks. I did search for existing questions but didn't find that one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you have a very nice explanation:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Some hints:

> Java and .NET unfortunately do not support `\X` (yet). Use `\P{M}\p{M}*` as a substitute. To match any number of graphemes, use `(?:\P{M}\p{M}*)+` instead of `\X+`.

> In Java, the regex token `\uFFFF` only matches the specified code point, even when you turned on canonical equivalence. However, the same syntax `\uFFFF` is also used to insert Unicode characters into literal strings in the Java source code. `Pattern.compile("\u00E0")` will match both the single-code-point and double-code-point encodings of `à`, while `Pattern.compile("\\u00E0")` matches only the single-code-point version. Remember that when writing a regex as a Java string literal, backslashes must be escaped. The former Java code compiles the regex `à`, while the latter compiles `\u00E0`. Depending on what you're doing, the difference may be significant.

Comment: Thanks. That page also points out why `\p{L}` is **not** sufficient to match any letter (you need `\p{L}\p{M}*`)

Comment: This should be edited to show the double slash in one of the Pattern.compile statements.

Comment: how to replace a unicode char - example `Test™`  to `Test`. Remove the TradeMark symbol i.e `™` from the string. I tried `"Test™".replace("™", "")` but it works on window and fails on linux build machine etc.

Answer (score 5):

Are you talking about Unicode categories, like letters? These are matched by a regex of the form `\p{CAT}`, where "CAT" is the category code like `L` for any letter, or a subcategory like `Lu` for uppercase or `Lt` for title-case.

Comment: @Pointy - You're right, you don't need to specify the sub-category.

Comment: Could well. I'd managed to provide the link to the Java spec and not notice that it says `Both \p{L} and \p{IsL} denote the category of Unicode letters` as an example :( A list of categories is here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm

Comment: Although see @eLobato's answer for why that '\p{L}' isn't sufficient.

Comment: how to replace a unicode char - example `Test™`  to `Test`. Remove the TradeMark symbol i.e `™` from the string. I tried `"Test™".replace("™", "")` but it works on window and fails on linux build machine etc.

Comment: @Victor like the other answers explain, replace `™` in your source code with its Unicode escape, `\u2122`. If it works on one machine and not another, it's probably due to the default character encoding being different on different machines, and the source code being read differently when it's compiled on the other machine. Restricting your source code to US-ASCII characters by replacing other characters with the `\uXXXX` escape will avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the JavaDoc of [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

> Unicode support
>
> This class is in conformance with
>   Level 1 of Unicode Technical Standard #18: [Unicode Regular Expression Guidelines](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/), plus RL2.1 Canonical Equivalents.
>
> Unicode escape sequences such as
>   \u2014 in Java source code are
>   processed as described in [§3.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#100850) of the
>   Java Language Specification. Such
>   escape sequences are also implemented
>   directly by the regular-expression
>   parser so that Unicode escapes can be
>   used in expressions that are read from
>   files or from the keyboard. Thus the
>   strings "\u2014" and "\\u2014", while
>   not equal, compile into the same
>   pattern, which matches the character
>   with hexadecimal value 0x2014.
>
> Unicode blocks and categories are
>   written with the \p and \P constructs
>   as in Perl. \p{prop} matches if the
>   input has the property prop, while
>   \P{prop} does not match if the input
>   has that property. Blocks are
>   specified with the prefix In, as in
>   InMongolian. Categories may be
>   specified with the optional prefix Is:
>   Both \p{L} and \p{IsL} denote the
>   category of Unicode letters. Blocks
>   and categories can be used both inside
>   and outside of a character class.
>
> The supported categories are those of
>   The Unicode Standard in the version
>   specified by the Character class. The
>   category names are those defined in
>   the Standard, both normative and
>   informative. The block names supported
>   by Pattern are the valid block names
>   accepted and defined by
>   UnicodeBlock.forName.

Comment: The formatter is eating the double slash. This should say: Thus the strings "\u2014" and "\\u2014", while not equal...

Comment: how to replace a unicode char - example `Test™`  to `Test`. Remove the TradeMark symbol i.e `™` from the string. I tried `"Test™".replace("™", "")` but it works on window and fails on linux build machine etc.