# Java unicode regex not matching german characters

Tags: java, regex

This question is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315330/matching-e-g-a-unicode-letter-with-java-regexps).

I am using `\P{M}\p{M}*` in order to match all letters (both from German and French language).

I chose this regex in order to avoid defining every unicode character such as:
`^[a-zA-Z[\\u00c0-\\u01ff]]+[\\']?(([-]?[a-zA-Z[\\u00c0-\\u01ff]]*[\\s]?)|([\\s]?[a-zA-Z[\\u00c0-\\u01ff]]*[-]?)){1,2}[a-zA-Z[\\u00c0-\\u01ff]]+$`

However, despite using the unicode format defined in the previous question, characters such as `ß` or `è` are not matched by the regex.

I am using JDK 6.

What am I missing. Thanks!

Comment: could you post some code snippet/failing test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the posix character class `\p{L}` for "any letter":

```
System.out.println("abcßè".matches("\\p{L}+")); // true
```

Comment: I'm receiving this exception: `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {Latin} near index 10 \p{IsLatin}+`. I'm guessing that there is something wrong with the format but I have no idea what.

Comment: Did you perhaps code `"\\p{Latin}"` instead of `"\\p{IsLatin}"`? Anyway, I just realised you can simply use `"\\p{L}"` for "any letter" - see updated answer.

Comment: It is `IsLatin`. For insctance you can test it here: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ and you'll get the same error

Comment: That site doesn't understand `\p{IsLatin}` but **does** understand `\p{L}` (maybe JDK version thing). Have you tried `"\\p{L}"` like my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

using java 6 this code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str = "hello ß you";
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(:?\\P{M}\\p{M}*)+");
       Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
       System.out.println("replaced: '" + matcher.replaceAll("") + "'");
}
```

returns: replaced: ''

The 'ß' is matched

Comment: Hi! Thanks but it seems that this pattern also matches digits and other special chars like `_` or space.