# Unicode Regex in Scala REPL

Tags: java, regex, scala, unicode, read-eval-print-loop

I want to detect words of Unicode Letters (`\p{L}`).

Scala's REPL gives back `false` for the following statement, while in Java it's `true` (which is the right behaviour):

`java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\p{L}").matcher("ä").matches()`

Both Java and Scala are running in JRE 1.7:

`System.getProperty("java.version")` gives back `"1.7.0_60-ea"`

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315330/matching-e-g-a-unicode-letter-with-java-regexps for why your regex isn't quite sufficient. You need `\p{L}\p{M}*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Probably a non-compatible character encoding used within the interpreter.** For example, here's my output:

```
scala> System.getProperty("file.encoding")
res0: String = UTF-8

scala> java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\p{L}").matcher("ä").matches()
res1: Boolean = true
```

So the solution is to run `scala` with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. Note, however, [this blog post](http://richard.dallaway.com/setting-the-character-encoding-in-scala) (which is a bit old) :

> The only reliable way we've found for setting the default character
>   encoding for Scala is to set $JAVA_OPTS before running your
>   application:
>
> `$ JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=utf8" scala`
>   [...]
>   Just trying to set `scala -Dfile.encoding=utf8` doesn't seem to do it. [...]

---

Wasn't the case here, but may also happen: alternatively, your "ä" could be [a diaeresis (umlaut)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29) sign followed by "a", e.g.:

```
scala> println("a\u0308")                                                                                             
ä                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
scala> java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\p{L}").matcher("a\u0308").matches()                                         
res1: Boolean = false
```

This is sometimes a problem on some systems which create diacritics through [Unicode combining characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/308/index.htm) (I think OS X is one, at least in some versions). For more info, [see Paul's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315330/matching-e-g-a-unicode-letter-with-java-regexps).

Comment: That's it. `scala> System.getProperty("file.encoding")` gives me `res0: String = Cp1252` since I'm on Windows. Thank you for the information.

Comment: @pvorb: thanks for the info, I'll edit the post to highlight the "main" solution accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can also "Enable the Unicode version of Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes" as described in [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)

This means you can use character classes such as '\w' to match Unicode characters like this:

```
"(?U)\\w+".r.findFirstIn("pässi")
```

In the regexp above '(?U)' bit is an Embedded Flag Expressions that turns on the UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag for the regexp.

This flag is supported starting from Java 7.