# Replacing text between quotes

Tags: jquery, regex

I have following string say:

```
var str = "This is 'first text' and now this is 'second', and many more contents goes here.";
```

Now I want to replace text between first two quotes `first text` with `some text` and next other two quotes with some text like `second` with `some more text`

The final string should be something like:

```
This is 'some text' and now this is 'some more text', and many more contents goes here.
```

Actually I have to make these two replaces on text change event of two textbox. Up till now, I can replace with specific text only, and not with above conditions.

Comment: Any suggestion downvoters

Comment: sry i not a down voters but my question is why u can split the string using(**) and replace the text using jquery

Comment: atleast some one please suggest withs problem with post, is it not clear, or duplicate any thing, please at least say something

Comment: I think it's because you haven't shown any effort to solve the problem first.

Comment: ** i have formated as bold not its symbol

Comment: @Jerry, i mentioned there that i am able to replace some string with other string, but with the above question i was not able to find any link , so i am stuck there

Comment: Then u can split the text using space and based on the arry value u change the string

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/498fv/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny you should provide it as an answer.

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/498fv/2/

Comment: Not a answer however sharing as pointer that might help in your case. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888124/how-to-replace-any-occurrence-of-a-word-between-quotes?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the content based on a text match then try

```
var str = "This is 'fisrt text' and now this is 'second', and many more contents goes here.";

var map = {
    "'fisrt text'": "'some text'",
    "'second'": "'more text'"
}

var str2 = str.replace(/'.*?'/g, function (str) {
    return map[str] || ''
});
console.log(str2)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/498fv/)

---

If you want to replace it with position(index)

```
var str = "This is 'fisrt text' and now this is 'second', and many more contents goes here.";

var array = ["'some text'",
    "'more text'"],
    i = 0;

var str2 = str.replace(/'.*?'/g, function (str) {
    return array[i++] || ''
});
console.log(str2)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3S3mP/)

Comment: It is strange to choose to remove quoted content as default behavior. Why haven't you choose to do nothing? (i.e. `return map[str] || str;`)

Comment: @Arun , is it not possible some way to find the position of first two quotes and then replace text between them, similar for another two quotes

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam ignore previous one... in that case why can't you use the second version like - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3S3mP/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny can u please put alert rathter than console, please

Comment: both text will be replace one by one, so i just want to in a function to replace text between first two quotes with a text, and then another function to replace text between 3 and 4th quotes with some text, sorry @ArunPJohny for being so demanding

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam why is it

Comment: i have to replace only one text at a time,

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam can you give a sample text and desired output with 4 quotes

Comment: actually there will be four quotes in a text, but on change of first textbox it will replace text between first two quotes with text of textbox, and similar way on change of second textbox it will replace text between 3rd and 4th quotes with second textbox text.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50027/discussion-between-md-parvez-alam-and-arun-p-johny)