# How to identify that the given string ends with newline or not

Tags: java

In java how to identify that the provided string ends with newline character or not?

Comment: get the last character and check if its a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A newline is an OS-dependant concept. On Unix it's one character (linefeed - U+000A), on Windows it's two characters (carriage return + linefeed, U+000D U+000A), it could be ven the newline character (NEL, U+0085, which I think may be used by some mainframes).

Some regular expression engines accept `\R` to mean a newline. Tom Christiansen defines `\R` for Java as the following:

```
\R => (?:(?>\u000D\u000A)|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])
```

at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261).

Then, you would use a regex like `\R$`, or, in Java `\\R$`, to mean "ends in newline".

Comment: Java does not have \R as a regex group, sorry.

Comment: @javamonkey79: Then use the substitution provided. D'oh.

Answer (score 5):

If you want know system new line separator:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

and :

```
function String.endsWith()
```

Comment: newline may be \n(unix) or  \r\n(Windows). Shal i go with this... string.endsWith(\\r?\\n)

Comment: endsWith doesn't accept regex so no. it should be string.endsWith(System.getProperty("line.separator")) (you might wanna cashe the line separator so you don't keep calling the getProperty each time)

Answer (score 0):

```
String superString = "This is a string\n";

if (superString.charAt(superString.length()-1) == "\n")
{
    ...
}
```

Although, I don't code in Java. But [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&xhr=t&q=java+get+last+character+of+string&cp=21&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=java+get+last+charact&pbx=1&fp=a19d57c9b1bb4a83) is my friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

String have method call public boolean endsWith(String suffix)

so by using above method we can find the new line character

`string.public boolean endsWith("\n");`

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the string in UTF-8 format if it is not there. There using characterAT (), last two character with '\n' and '\r'.

Comment: Strings in java are encoding independent (its internally represented as UTF-16, but you needn't to care about it, java do it for you)

Comment: @bugs_ i know in java strings by default UTF-16 but you can format the String s = "some text here"; byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); and then you can find out.