# Regex in JavaScript acting differently than elsewhere

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match the word ethane (preceded with nothing) while avoiding methane.  I've tried this in an online regex tester: `/(?<!m)ethane/i` (which works), but I get an invalid regex expression error in JavaScript.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using https://regex101.com/, make sure you select javascript, in flavor, instead of php. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent

Comment: JavaScript doesn't currently support look-behind patterns. Though, there's [an active proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) for adding them (at the moment, the proposal is a "Candidate," [stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#active-proposals)).

Comment: Neat, good to know.  So if I'm using JavaScript, how would I match on "ethane" and not "methane"?

Comment: You can try to use the "starts with" anchor. /^ethane/i . But this will force the string to start with 'ethane' (so for example it would match 'ethane', but not 'methane', and not 'word ethane')

Comment: Do you want to match "ethane" as a separate word, or just those letters as long as they don't follow an "m"? Are "polyurethane" and/or "ethanediol" supposed to match?

Comment: I want to match "Ethane", "ethane", " ethane", " ethane ", "ethane " (case-insensitive.  I don't anticipate anything coming before "ethane" besides potentially some whitespace (tabula/ocr reasons).  But methane usually shows up before ethane in the table I'm parsing.  I've collected the methane row of the table, now I want to match on the ethane row of the table.  Hope that helps!  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: When testing your regexps in a regexp tester, make sure to select the "JavaScript" flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` `/\bethane\b/` to match `"ethane"` and not `"methane"`

```js
var thanes = ["ethane", "methane"];
var re = /\bethane\b/;
thanes.forEach(word => console.log(re.test(word)));
```

See

- [Difference between \b and \B in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex)
- [How does \b work when using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605198/how-does-b-work-when-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me links for explanation too!