# Regex expression does not match in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

What I am missing here?

```
import re
sample = 'this is an example'
p = re.compile('this is\b\w+\bexample')
p.findall(sample)
[]
```

Shouldn't the pattern match?  `\b\w+\b` should match `space + an + space` or not?

Comment: Read more about word boundaries, they are *non-consuming* patterns, zero-width assertions that do not actually match any chars, but *positions*.

Comment: **Duplicate of [How does \b work when using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605198/how-does-b-work-when-using-regular-expressions)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because neither `\b`, nor `\w` matches spaces.

```
import re
sample = "this is an example"
r = re.findall(r"this is\s+\w+\s+example", sample)
print(r)
```

See [this demo](https://www.ideone.com/s5V7FH).