# Why in this regex pattern left \b performs as left \B?

Tags: regex, nlp, boundary

Why in this case left `\b` performs as left `\B`?

```
\b\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?\b
```

This pattern should omit phrases such `a$99.99` because of performance of left `\b`.

`\b` detects phrases which  have  not been bounded with letters, digits or underscore. But not! I examined it in regex101.
[as you see it detects phrases such `tyh666.8` but doesn't detect `$99`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndwxy.jpg)

However, right `\b` performs completely correctly!

Surprisingly, I changed it to left `\B` it worked!

`\B` detects phrases which have been bounded with letters, digits or underscore. But here it works as a left `\b`!
and I have no idea why?!

[As you see it detects phrases which have not been bounded with letters, digits or underscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixcpb.jpg)

Comment: `\b\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?\b` matches `a$99.99`: The `\b` is matching between the `a` and `$`. `$99` does **not** match because there is no word boundary between a space and `$`. A `\b` matches *between* a word char and a non-word char, and between a non-word char and a word char (where a "word char" is `0-9a-zA-Z_]`). Read [Difference between `\b` and `\B` in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/256196).

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7606358/4225384): `The word boundary \b matches on a change from a \w (a word character) to a \W a non word character, or from \W to \w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of `\b` is incorrect. It matches positions where there are "word" characters on one side, and "not word" characters on the other. `$` is not a word character, so it will only match where `$` is immediately preceded by a word character (alphanumerics, plus in some implementations e.g. `@` and `_`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure *all* implementations of `\b` agree that a word char is `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`. Can you quote references to any variations to this?

Comment: My memories are vague, but IIRC some programming languages have hacked the "word" class to coincide with their "identifier" or "token" class for their own convenience.