# Is "\n" a vertical whitespace, i.e., should "\v" match it?

Tags: java, regex, perl, unicode

Logically, it is (but logic is irrelevant whenever character encodings or locales are in play). According to

```
perl -e 'print "\n" =~ /\v/ ? "y\n" : "n\n";'
```

printing "y", it is. According to

```
Pattern.compile("\\v").matcher("\n").matches();
```

returning `false` in java, it's not. This wouldn't confuse me at all, if there weren't [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261) claiming that

> Sun’s updated Pattern class for JDK7 has a marvelous new flag, UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS, which makes everything work right again.

But I'm using java version "1.7.0_07" and the flag exists and seems to change nothing at all. Moreover, "\n" is no newcomer to Unicode but a plain old ASCII character, so I really don't see how this difference may happen. Probably I'm doing something stupid, but I can't see it.

Comment: As best as I can tell, Unicode doesn't have a vertical whitespace property. It's purely a Perl construct that matches the following characters: U+000A, U+000B, U+000C, U+000D, U+0085, U+2028 and U+2029. Just use a character class matching those characters instead.

Comment: @ikegami: Funny. I've just found [this list](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/PropList.txt) agreeing with you.

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Escape Sequences".

Comment: Note that since Java 8, `\v` means vertical whitespace

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Java 7's Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) explicitly mentions `\v` in its "list of Perl constructs not supported by this class". So it's not that `\n` doesn't belong to Java's category of "vertical whitespace"; it's that Java 7 doesn't *have* a category of "vertical whitespace". Instead, Java 7 regexes have an undocumented feature whereby they interpret `\v` as referring to the vertical tab character, [U+000B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/index.htm). (This is a traditional escape sequence from C/C++/Bash/etc., though Java string literals *don't* support it. Likewise with `\a` for alert/bell and `\cX` for control-character `X`.)

**Edited to add:** This has changed in newer versions of Java. According to [Java **8**'s Javadoc for `java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\v` now means "A vertical whitespace character: `[\n\x0B\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]`".

Comment: That's true and something I should have spotted myself. However, unlike many other undefined constructs like e.g. `Pattern.compile("\\C")` it throws no `PatternSyntaxException`. In the source code I've finally found that it matches `U+000B`, i.e. "vertical tab" only. Sounds funny.

Comment: @maaartinus: `\v` is a traditional escape sequence for vertical tab (in the same group as `\n`, `\r`, and so on), and although Java doesn't support it in string literals (per section 3.10.6 of the JLS), there are a few similar non-Java escape sequences that `java.util.regex.Pattern` supports (`\a` for alert/bell, `\cX` for control-character `X`). The only funny business here, IMHO, is the mismatch between documentation and implementation: the Javadoc for `Pattern` lists all the escape sequences it's supposed to support, including `\n` and so on, and it doesn't mention `\v`.

Comment: That's it. I think I add it to your answer as this was the thing that confused me.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to OP: since Java 8, `\v` and `\V` are supported: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @IARI: Thanks for the heads-up. I've now updated the answer to explain that.

Answer (score 11):

`perldoc perlrecharclass` says that `\v` matches a "vertical whitespace character".  This is further explained:

> "\v" matches any character considered vertical whitespace; this
>   includes the platform's carriage return and line feed characters
>   (newline) plus several other characters, all listed in the table
>   below.  "\V" matches any character not considered vertical whitespace.
>   They use the platform's native character set, and do not consider any
>   locale that may otherwise be in use.

Specifically, `\v` matches the following characters in 5.16:

```
$ unichars -au '\v'           # From Unicode::Tussle
 ---- U+0000A LINE FEED
 ---- U+0000B LINE TABULATION
 ---- U+0000C FORM FEED
 ---- U+0000D CARRIAGE RETURN
 ---- U+00085 NEXT LINE
 ---- U+02028 LINE SEPARATOR
 ---- U+02029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
```

You could use a character class to get the same effect as Perl's `\v`.

Of course this applies to Perl; I don't know whether it applies to Java.