# Regular expression to match any vertical whitespace

Tags: .net, regex, perl, whitespace, multiline

Is there a regex pattern for .NET that will match any character that will result in multiple lines, i.e. any vertical whitespace character, like perl regex does with `\v`?  In other words, is there a way to match `\r` (carriage return), `\n` (line feed), `\v` (vertical tab), and `\f` (form feed) as well as the Unicode characters `U+0085` (next line), `U+2028` (line separator), and `U+2029` (paragraph separator) and any other characters I'm not aware of that might result in more than one line?

I'm writing some validation code in .NET that will fail if a user has provided input text that contains more than one line.  In most cases, that means I just have to check for `\r` and `\n`.  However, I know there is a multitude of other vertical [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

I know [.NET regex differs from perl regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417644/translate-perl-regular-expressions-to-net), most importantly in that `\v` in .NET matches "vertical tab" whereas it matches "vertical whitespace" in perl regex.

Comment: The [perl docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) on re classes claim that the perl regex engine behaves as desired on `\v` (I haven't checked that empirically).

Comment: What dialect of regex are you using? What is your programming language (and version)? Does perl's `\v` work for you? (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290224/is-n-a-vertical-whitespace-i-e-should-v-match-it for a list of characters n that class.)

Comment: According to the [Unicode character property for  whitespace cited on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), the list behnind the link in @ChristopherCreutzig's comment is exhaustive (\x0a-\x0d, \x85, u+2028, u+2029).

Comment: You can use `\R` in Perl that stands for a generic newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the Perl character class `\v` matches `[\x0A-\x0D]` (linefeed, vertical tab, form feed and carriage-return (although I would dispute that CR is vertical white space)) in addition to the non-ASCII code points `[\x{2028}\x{2029}]` (line separator and paragraph separator).

You can hand-build this character class in .NET like this

```
[\u0A-\u0D\u2028\u2029]
```

Comment: @roryap: I'm pleased to help. I modified your question by moving the last paragraph to the beginning. I think it still reads well. It seemed that people who hadn't read to the end were getting the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: @roryap: You might think it more readable written as `[\r\v\f\n\u2028\u2029]`. I don't think there's a way of adding characters to a .NET string using their Unicode names, which would have been ideal.

Comment: Thanks again.  Too bad .NET doesn't have a single char escape like perl does with `\v` for vertical whitespace, but, as you pointed out that's only for ASCII and wouldn't include the two additional Unicode characters `\u2028` and `u2029`.

Comment: @roryap: You misunderstand me: those six code points are what Perl's `\v` character class matches. A literal Perl equivalent would be `[\r\N{VERTICAL TABULATION}\f\n\N{LINE SEPARATOR}\N{PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR}]`. It's not a definitive list of vertical whitespace characters, and you may want to add to it if you find other characters that cause trouble.

Comment: Ahh, I misread it then.  You said "As you say, the Perl character class \v matches [\x0A-\x0D]" which I interpreted as being exhaustive, but you then said "And if you're also interested in non-ASCII code points **then it includes** [\x{2028}\x{2029}]"

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to match any unknowns simply us the *not* set `[^ ]` (at least in .Net, my perl is a little hazy) to match up to a specific character. For example if I wanted to match whitespace between from a current position across a line to the next line which starts with the letter `D` I would use this

`([^D]+)`

So the match capture would include every type of whitespace there is up to the letter D.