# How Can I Use Look-Ahead and Look-Behind to Create a Custom Boundary Matcher?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I want to split a String at the word boundaries using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Normally, this would be done like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(...).useDelimiter("\\b");
```

The problem is that my definition of "word" character is a tiny bit different from the standard `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` as I want to include some more characters and exclude the `_`: `[a-zA-Z0-9#/]`. Therefore, I can't use the `\b` pattern.

So I tried to do the same thing using look-ahead and look-behind, but what I came up with didn't work:

```
(<?=[A-Za-z0-9#/])(?![A-Za-z0-9#/])|(<?![A-Za-z0-9#/])(?=[A-Za-z0-9#/])
```

The scanner doesn't split anywhere using this.

Is it possible to do this using look-ahead and look-behind and how?

Comment: Just a minor point, but your "standard" definition of `\b` is also wrong.

Comment: I didn't give one, but I assume it is something like `(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w)`.

Comment: That's how it's *supposed* to be defined, and if you use Java 7 and its new [UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) mode, it is.  But Java's legacy `\b` is a bit more...creative.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4304928/20938) for details, especially @tchrist's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an error in your syntax. The `?` comes first:

```
(?<=[A-Za-z0-9#/])(?![A-Za-z0-9#/])|(?<![A-Za-z0-9#/])(?=[A-Za-z0-9#/])
 ^^                                  ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Scanner(...).useDelimiter(
  "(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9#/])(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9#/])|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9#/])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9#/])");
```

Comment: No, that requires a character in front and a character behind, so it won't match a word boundary at the beginning or end of the string.  The OP has the right formula, he just made a slight error with the syntax.

Comment: He's trying to create an equivalent for `\b` that conforms to his definition of word characters.  His corrected regex works exactly the same as yours when they're used with Scanner's `useDelimiter()` method--which, I admit, I hadn't realized when I wrote my comment.  But I think my point is still valid: your answer may solve his problem, but it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: @AlanMoore - Read his question again - it says: `I want to split a string...`

Comment: Okay, the question he *should* have been asking. :P  The problem with his own solution was in the syntax, not the semantics.

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong with:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9#/]+
```

in other words any run of at least one character in the set that is not your word set

or if you need the spaces

```
[^A-Za-z0-9#/ ]+
```

and then strip the spaces out for special processing after the scanner (if needed)

Comment: I need the spaces between the words as well. The scanner would swallow them using your regex.

Comment: I think OP wants spaces as separate "words"/tokens or whatever we will call it :)