# Character class for Unicode digits

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a `Pattern` that will match all Unicode digits and alphabetic characters.  So far I have `"\\p{IsAlphabetic}|[0-9]"`.

The first part is working well for me, it's doing a good job of identifying non-Latin characters as alphabetic characters.  The problem is the second half.  Obviously it will only work for Arabic Numerals.  The character classes `\\d` and `\p{Digit}` are also just `[0-9]`.  The javadoc for `Pattern` does not seem to mention a character class for Unicode digits.  Does anyone have a good solution for this problem?

For my purposes, I would accept a way to match the set of all characters for which `Character.isDigit` returns `true`.

Comment: Is 'unicode digit' actually a well-defined concept?

Comment: To a certain degree, I'd say yes.  The Character class has an isDigit method which returns true for non-Latin digits (I've been testing with Japanese numerals).

Comment: What happens if you use Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS like in `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)` ?

Comment: This might help: - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4307261/1679863

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann. That is only added in `Java 7`.

Comment: Well, maybe the OP is using Java 7 :)

Comment: As it happens, the OP is using Java 7 =)

Comment: @Pillar I had a good look for a dupe, but didn't find one. Well done - it's a dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28int%29) about `isDigit`:

> A character is a digit if its general category type, provided by getType(codePoint), is DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER.

So, I believe the pattern to match digits should be [`\p{Nd}`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category).

Here's a [working example](http://ideone.com/jnxtlR) at ideone. As you can see, the results are consistent between `Pattern.matches` and `Character.isDigit`.

Comment: Simply `\p{N}` works: `System.out.println("3๓३".matches("\\p{N}+")) // true`

Comment: @Bohemian But `p{N}` also matches `Nl` and `No`, which `isDigit` does not match. [Example](http://ideone.com/1GHJ1P). Sometimes you *want* to match those, but since the OP asked for a behavior consistent with `isDigit`, I answered with just `Nd`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `\d`, but with the `(?U)` flag to enable the Unicode version of predefined character classes and POSIX character classes:

```
(?U)\d+
```

or in code:

```
System.out.println("3๓३".matches("(?U)\\d+")); // true
```

Using `(?U)` is equivalent to compiling the regex by calling [`Pattern.compile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-) with the [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

Comment: One of the rare occasions where I don't think a duplicate post deserves a downvote. New answer and all that. Don't you have merge powers, or does that not apply here?

Comment: @Pillar so merged. IMHO this answer is easier to remember and understand - who can remember all those funky posix classes?

Comment: What POSIX classes do you mean? POSIX character classes are `[:punct:]`, `[:digit:]`, etc. `\p{N}`, or `\p{L}` etc. are Unicode category classes (term used in .NET), or Unicode character properties (term used in PHP), and these are very handy, especially `\p{Ll}` and `\p{Lu}`. In Java, certainly `(?U)\d` looks preferable.