# Regex to match some number of upper case characters at the beginning of a String

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone recommend a Regex that would match on the following rules:

- Upper case or a space

My strings that I want to match look like this

`LONDON 10 Downing St, London`

or this

`NEW YORK  2859 Broadway, New York, NY 10025`

I want to be able to match the words LONDON and NEW YORK when I pass in each line.

P.S. I am doing this in Java

Comment: Hmm. So did you attempt anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Beginning of the string: `^`
- Uppercase letter: `\p{Lu}`
- Space:
- Combining the two: `[\p{Lu} ]`
- Any number of the preceding token: `*`
- Assertion that the match ends at the end of a word (requires Java 7 to work reliably): `\b`

Your regex, therefore, is

```
^[\p{Lu} ]*\b
```

Don't forget to double the backslashes to comply with Java's string escaping rules:

In Java 7:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{Lu} ]*\\b", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

In Java 6 and below:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{Lu} ]*(?<=\p{Lu})");
```

Comment: Does `\b` not work in Java 6 and below? I didn't know that.

Comment: @arshajii: [It only matches at ASCII word boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4304928/20670).

Comment: If you're not coding for/in Java 7, use `(?<=\p{Lu})` instead of `\b`. That's a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) making sure that the previous character is an uppercase letter.

Comment: Tim, it may be that even in Java 7 you will need `(?u)` or `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` to get the `\b` to work with non-ASCII. I’d check to make sure. I would have to look up the mailing list discussions from 2–3 years ago to see what the resolution was to the `\b` mess.

Comment: @tchrist: [The docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) seem to suggest that you do need to set that flag explicitly (or use `(?U)` with an uppercase `U`). Thanks!

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oops, right: yes, it’s an uppercase `(?U)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
^[A-Z ]+
```

This will match one or more upper case Latin letters or spaces from the beginning of the string.

You can easily modify this to avoid capturing trailing spaces:

```
^[A-Z ]*[A-Z]
```

Comment: It will always end with one or more spaces, though.

Comment: @Jongware I've provided a modified version of the pattern to exclude trailing spaces, if that's required.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
^\u+( \u+)*
```

It matches a number of uppercase characters, optionally followed by groups of (single space, more uppercase characters). This will avoid always ending with a space.

Comment: `\u` is not a valid regex token in any regex flavor I know, and most certainly not in Java (unless you can show me the documentation that says so).

Comment: @tim-pietzcker: how very odd. It's available in [InDesign](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSFB3603CC-8D84-48d8-9F77-F3E0644CB0B6a.html#WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6f59a), and InDesign's GREP uses boost. Never thought Adobe would invent such a useful shortcut! Seems you have to use the Posix shorthand or the explicit range [A-Z] after all.

Comment: It would be nice if Regex could be more intuitive.

Comment: @Ankur What does “intuitive” mean?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Well, yes and no and maybe.  There are places where `\u` means to convert the next code point to titlecase, but that’s not technically at the regex level.  It derives from the popularity of being able to say `:%s/[a-z]+/\u\L&/g` in the `vi` editor: notice it falls on the replacement side not the search side, which means that it is really a string not a pattern. Perl uses it that way, where it compiles into a call to the `ucfirst` function, which in turn maps to the Unicode titlecase version of that next code point.