# Extract Arabic phrases from a given text in java

Tags: java, regex, arabic, phrases

Can you help me in finding a regex that take list of phrases and check if one of these phrases exist in the given text, please?

Example:

If I have in the `hashSet` the following words:

```
كيف الحال  
إلى أين  
أين يوجد  
هل من أحد هنا
```

And the given text is: `كيف الحال أتمنى أن تكون بخير`

I want to get after performing regex: `كيف الحال`

My initial code:

```
HashSet<String> QWWords = new HashSet<String>();

QWWords.add("كيف الحال");
QWWords.add("إلى أين");
QWWords.add("أين يوجد");
QWWords.add("هل من أحد هنا");

String s1 = "كيف الحال أتمنى أن تكون بخير";

for (String qp : QWWords) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\s" + qp + "\\s]");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);

    String found = "";

    while (m.find()) {
        found = m.group();
        System.out.println(found);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[...]` is [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and character class can match only one character it specifies. For instance character class like `[abc]` can match only `a` OR `b` OR `c`. So if you want to find only word `abc` don't surround it with `[...]`.

Another problem is that you are using `\\s` as word separator, so in following String

```
String data = "foo foo foo foo";
```

regex `\\sfoo\\s` will not be able to match first `foo` because *there is no space before*.
So first match it will find will be

```
String data = "foo foo foo foo";
//      this one--^^^^^
```

Now, since regex consumed space after second `foo` it can't reuse it in next match so third `foo` will also be skipped because there is no space available to match before it.
You will also not match forth `foo` because this time there is no space *after* it.

To solve this problem you can use `\\b` - [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) which checks if place it represents is between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters (or start/end of string).

So instead of

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\s" + qp + "\\s]");
```

use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + qp + "\\b");
```

or maybe better as [Tim mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710720/extract-arabic-phrases-from-a-given-text-in-java/23711106#comment36439206_23711106)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + qp + "\\b",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

to make sure that `\\b` will include Arabic characters in predefined alphanumeric class.

UPDATE:

I am not sure if your words can contain regex metacharacters like `{` `[` `+` `*` and so on, so just in case you can also add escaping mechanism to change such characters into literals.

So

```
"\\b" + qp + "\\b"
```

can become

```
"\\b" + Pattern.quote(qp) + "\\b"
```

Comment: +1, but be sure to use `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`, or [`\b` won't match at a non-ASCII word boundary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4304928/20670).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Originally I used this flag but just wanted to test results without it and to my surprise it worked correctly so it seems that `\\b` recognised Arabic characters as valid character. Anyway I added this flag in my answer as you suggested (just to be safe).

Comment: @TimPietzcker From http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html "*Java supports Unicode for `\b` but not for `\w`*".

Comment: Thank you too much, it works for me. I appreciate your quick help.

Comment: Thank you also for the information that you gave about regex as I am new in using regex.