# Extract Arabic text from mixed text in java

Tags: java

i have a mixed text arabic , english , numbers & special charcters.
How can i extract the arabic text only in java ?

Example :

```
مرحبا كيفك i'm fine and you كله تمام . كم عمرك . my age is 18
```

needed output :

```
مرحبا كيفك كله تمام كم عمرك
```

Comment: Use regex to remove inwanted characters from string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Arabic phrases from a given text in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710720/extract-arabic-phrases-from-a-given-text-in-java)

Comment: OR --> [Extracting Arabic words from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852871/extracting-arabic-wordsnot-semantic-arabic-phrases-from-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression `\p{InArabic}` matches any Arabic letter.  The regular expression `\s` matches any whitespace character.  So if you only wish to see Arabic letters and spaces, you could use something like

```
myString.replaceAll("[^\\p{InArabic}\\s]", "");
```

to remove everything other than Arabic letters and whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

write a regex statement that only accepts arabic characters. This one should get the job done : `^[\u0621-\u064A0-9 ]+$`

it accepts all the arabic unicode characters, if that doesn't do exactly what you need, it at least gives you something to start with

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest approach would be to look for characters in the range 0x600-0x6FF in the string. You should be able to do this with a regexp replace along the lines of

```
myString.replaceAll([^\\p{IsArabic}]);
```

(untested, and this requires Java 7 or later) but this would remove any characters from the string which aren't Arabic. Otherwise you'd need to replace `\p{...}` with `\\x{600}-\\x{6ff}` assuming I'm remembering my regexp hex syntax correctly.

Comment: It's supposed to be `IsArabic`, not `isArabic`. More info at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: It cannot be compiled.