# Efficient Regular Expression for big data, if a String contains a word

Tags: java, regex, string, contains

I have a code that works but is extremely slow. This code determines whether a string contains a keyword. The requirements I have need to be efficient for hundreds of keywords that I will search for in thousands of documents.

What can I do to make finding the keywords (without falsely returning a word that contains the keyword) efficiently?

For example:

```
String keyword="ac"; 
String document"..."  //few page long file
```

If i use :

```
if(document.contains(keyword) ){
//do something
}
```

It will also return true if document contains a word like "account";

so I tried to use regular expression as follows:

```
String pattern = "(.*)([^A-Za-z]"+ keyword +"[^A-Za-z])(.*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(document);
if(m.find()){
   //do something
}
```

Summary:

This is the summary: Hopefully it will be useful to some one else:

1. My regular expression would work but extremely impractical while
   working with big data.  (it didn't terminate)
2. @anubhava perfected the regular expression.  it was easy to
   understand and implement. It managed to terminate which is a big
   thing. but it was still a bit slow. (Roughly about 240 seconds)
3. @Tomalak solution is abit complex to implement and understand but it
   was the fastest solution. so hats off mate.(18 seconds)

so @Tomalak solution was ~15 times faster than @anubhava.

Comment: Are you reading the files every time?

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking is the keyword you are looking for. Also *"if a string contains a word"* is checked with `indexOf()`, not with regular expressions.

Comment: all documents and keywords are in memory.

Comment: If you want to match "ac" but not "account", wouldn't your keyword be " ac "?

Comment: @Kayaman yes but its possible to have something like: "ac;" which also be matched

Comment: Well you could multi-thread / parallelise it, but essentially the only real way to do this is index the documents and search the index which will of course be slowish, but only needed once per document.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not quite sure what you mean by using "indexOf()". could you explain abit further please?

Comment: @nafas http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String) - in other words, can you explain why you use regex for this?

Comment: @Tomalak well if I use indexOf, I would have the same problem with contains. as I said I if I search for "ac" and document contains "account", it would still matches.

Comment: I see. That's a valid reason.

Comment: @Tomalak check the summary mate, thanks again.

Comment: Wow, that *is* one improvement. If you really care, try my suggestion with the `Character` class. It would take some thought what amounts to a non-word character (for your input data), but I think you could squeeze out a bit more performance, too.

Comment: @Tomalak I just used **{"," , " " , ";" , "\n" , "" , "\"" , "'" , " "}** as delimiters in a set. and improve the results by 4 seconds :D. so this time it took 14 seconds.

Comment: Also see this Gist: https://gist.github.com/Tomalak/31c1c55c1c79430be5c7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest-possible way to find substrings in Java is to use [`String.indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

To achieve "entire-word-only" matches, you would need to add a little bit of logic to check the characters before and after a possible match to make sure they are non-word characters:

```
public class IndexOfWordSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "There are longer strings than this not very long one.";
        String search = "long";
        int index = indexOfWord(input, search);

        if (index > -1) {
            System.out.println("Hit for \"" + search + "\" at position " + index + ".");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No hit for \"" + search + "\".");
        }
    }

    public static int indexOfWord(String input, String word) {
        String nonWord = "^\\W?$", before, after;               
        int index, before_i, after_i = 0;

        while (true) {
            index = input.indexOf(word, after_i);
            if (index == -1 || word.isEmpty()) break;

            before_i = index - 1;
            after_i = index + word.length();
            before = "" + (before_i > -1 ? input.charAt(before_i) : "");            
            after = "" + (after_i < input.length() ? input.charAt(after_i) : "");

            if (before.matches(nonWord) && after.matches(nonWord)) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This would print:

> Hit for "long" at position 44.

This should perform better than a pure regular expressions approach.

Think if `^\W?$` already matches your expectation of a "non-word" character. The regular expression is a compromise here and may cost performance if your input string contains many "almost"-matches.

For extra speed, ditch the regex and work with the [`Character` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), checking a combination of the many properties it provides (like `isAlphabetic`, etc.) for `before` and `after`.

I've created a Gist with an [alternative implementation that does that](https://gist.github.com/Tomalak/31c1c55c1c79430be5c7).

Comment: this was great mate, I almost got same results but even faster using this. (almost is more than perfect while working with big data)

Comment: I've added some info as to making this even faster.

Answer (score 4):

Don't think you need to have `.*` in your regex.

Try this regex:

```
String pattern = "\\b"+ Pattern.quote(keyword) + "\\b";
```

Here `\\b` is used for word boundary. If the keyword can contain special characters, make sure they are not at the start or end of the word, or the word boundaries will fail to match.

Also you must be using `Pattern.quote` if your keyword contains special regex characters.

**EDIT:** You might use this regex if your keywords are *separated by space*.

```
String pattern = "(?<=\\s|^)"+ Pattern.quote(keyword) + "(?=\\s|$)";
```

Comment: (and if the keyword can contain those characters, make sure they are not at the start or end of the word, or the word boundaries will fail to match).

Comment: @anubhava I tried your solution. its going much much faster. I'll update you in a bit :)

Comment: @anubhava `Pattern.quote()` is not optional, but *absolutely mandatory* in this situation. It's better to say "unless you have good reasons against it" than to indicate that it would somehow only be needed under certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak: I have recommended it strongly and added in the code also.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you very much, The results are absolutely wonderful. Its still slow but at least I finished :D. I guess if I run it on a cloud I can reduce the time consumption into real time now.

Comment: For fun and profit I'm linking to this encyclopedic answer about Unicode and `\b` (among other things) in Java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions

Comment: @nafas: Glad to know it helped reducing overall time taken in running your program.

Comment: @anubhava I thought you might be interested in this. check the summary on overall profermance