# Linkify hashtags based on match.group(1)

Tags: android, regex, linkify

I am trying to `Linkify` hashtags in a `TextView`.
Thats is working as sample code I provided but I need to underline found hashtags based on `match.group(1)`.
Linkify seems to underline based on `match.group(0)`.
With `TransformFilter` I can only change hashtag click destination not the preview of underline link.
As a summary, `Linkify` creates underlines on `match.group(0)` but I want underlines on `match.group(1)`

```
TextView tv_body = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_body);
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:^|\\W)#([A-Za-z\\d\u00E7\u011F\u0131\u015F\u00F6\u00FC\u00C7\u011E\u0130\u015E\u00D6\u00DC]+)");
String scheme = "search://";

TransformFilter filter = new TransformFilter()
{
    public final String transformUrl(final Matcher match, String url)
    {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "transformUrl - match.group(0):" + 
            match.group(0) + " - match.group(1):" + match.group(1));
        return match.group(1);
    }
};
Linkify.addLinks(tv_body, pattern, scheme, null, filter);
```

> transformUrl - match.group(0):##dene    - match.group(1):dene
>   transformUrl - match.group(0):#hashreal - match.group(1):hashreal 
>   transformUrl - match.group(0):+#arti    - match.group(1):arti
>   transformUrl - match.group(0):(#de      - match.group(1):de
>   transformUrl - match.group(0):#feriştah - match.group(1):feriştah

```
/*
tv_body text content:
nb#dnkjd
##dene
#hashreal
1#2
+#arti
%d(#de
#feriştah
şah#in
*/
```

Comment: if the Linkify implementation is not enough you can still use Spannable.setSpan with URLSpan/ClickableSpan span object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude the text matched by `(?:^|\\W)#`, enclose it in a look-behind:

```
(?<=(?:^|\\W)#)
```

Then you can drop the capturing group, and the main match will contain only the content after the `#`.

---

Before, I'd suggest this:

```
(?<=\B#)
```

However, after looking at [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043727) and [this question about inconsistency between \w and \b in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions), I'd say you need to be careful when using the shorter one, since `\b` and `\B`'s definition in default mode is not synced with `\w`.