# Regular expression for unicode in java Dash version

Tags: java, regex, unicode

It is possible to improve the performance of the following through a regular expression, the code is functional, but I want to know if there is any way to select the possible dash that exist in the unicode to standardize my dash

**Words:**

```
48553−FS002
48553-FS002
48553 FS002
48553-FS002-ESD12
```

**Java**

```
String reference = "48553−FS002";
String separador = reference.replaceFirst ( "\\w+(\\W)?\\w+", "$1" );
if(!separator.equals ( " " )) {
   reference = reference.replaceAll ( separator, "-" );
}
```

Or you could search for the unicode code, I was reading the following: **[dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)**, but i haven't managed to make it work **[Java Regex Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions)**

Comment: A dash regex is `\p{Pd}`. Together with a soft hyphen, it is `[\p{Pd}\u00AD]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i try but not found in all case  for example `48553−FS002` but others found

Comment: Ah, that is a minus sign, `\u2212`, add it. `[\p{Pd}\u00AD\u2212]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, I just found it, even a thousand and a thousand thanks and it's the same. `\u2212`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to match any non-word but space, you may use

```java
reference = reference.replaceAll("[^\\w ]", "-");
```

Or, with character class subtraction:

```java
reference = reference.replaceAll("[\\W&&[^ ]]", "-");
```

You can use the following pattern to match your hyphen or dash like patterns:

```java
[\p{Pd}\u00AD\u2212]
```

Here,

- `\p{Pd}` - matches any [Punctuation, Dash](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Pd) symbols
- `\u00AD` - matches a soft hyphen
- `\u2212` - matches a minus symbol.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your strings only contain word characters and separators, as seems to be the case, then you can just use

```java
reference = reference.replaceAll("[^ \\w]", "-");
```

Comment: `\W` pattern is currently used in the OP code.

Comment: Yes, and that is probably the best approach if the format of the strings is as shown.

Comment: Why? It is easier without any lookaheads, `"[^\\w ]"`. I already added it to my answer, BTW.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good to see you copying my approach.

Comment: You updated your answer **after** I did that. Literally 2 seconds after.